# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows start parameter

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hei, 
I want to start the bash.exe on windows with start parameters, and let the shell open.
I found the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/reference) for this, but if I try to run it with e.g. bash -c "ls" , the bash is already closed after.

I want to have a link on my desktop where I put in a login command for ssh. So the shell should stay open, and not perfom the command then exit.

Comment: After the command is completed, do you just want the shell window to be open, or you want it to be an interactive shell window? For first case, try `bash -c "ls; read -n1 -p 'Press any key to exit...'"`. Else for the latter case, try `bash -c "ls; exec bash"`

Comment: @anishsane yes the second one was what I wanted & it worked. thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/bash/)

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option
             argument command_string.  If there are arguments  after  the  command_string,
             they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

So, with `-c`, the shell is not interactive. If you want an interactive shell after the initial command is run, start another interactive bash shell from running bash shell.

With your example, it will be:

```
bash -c 'ls; exec bash'
```